# Add SDK via cocoapod

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have installed Fabric utility app on my Mac to integrate CrashLytics in my project. The screen having option to add SDK via POD file is not visible to select choice.
Need help in this regard with thanks.

[image]

Comment: as far as I know there is no step to include Fabric's SDK (with pod) into your project using their utility app

Comment: I believe you add it to your project via your Podfile first, then go through the setup process. It should detect that you already have the SDK & will adjust accordingly.

Comment: @hal9000 hope above image will help you to understand what i wand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

That screen will only show up if a podfile is detected. You can also see how to set this up [here,](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/fabric/cocoapods.html#manage-fabric-with-cocoapods) but you will need to know your API key and build secret.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I already have discovered it. But tell me one thing.How can i know my api key and build secret without Fabric utility program.

Comment: Thanks @Z, good to know. Currently when setting up your first app, the keys are only available through Fabric.app or the IDE plugin. After that, you can get them from your organization's settings page. Great to know you'd prefer an alternative approach - will share with the team.